# Regex is not searching string

Tags: java, regex

I am searching this string `package com.`

This is the code

```
Pattern l_pattern = Pattern.compile("package com\\.",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String l_entireFile=readEntireFile(p_filePath.toString());
String l_spiltCommentString []  =   l_pattern.split(l_entireFile);
```

But it is not searching the same in all the file.

I just want to know why it is showing this behavior.

Comment: it was not searching the contents because we have tab and double spaces in the package name.!!!Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape backslashes.

```
Pattern l_pattern = Pattern.compile("package com\\\\.",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

---

**UPDATE**

You don't need to use regular expression.

```
String l_spiltCommentString []  = l_entireFile.split("package com.");
```

### Package name contains spaces

Use following pattern.

```
Pattern l_pattern = Pattern.compile("package\\s+com\\.",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: I am putting \\ to escape '.'.

Comment: Thanks actually it was not searching the contents because we have tab and double spaces in the package name.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `.indexOf()`:

```
l_entireFile.indexOf("package com.") != -1
```

Also, if this is really a Java source file, there is no need for `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`: both keywords and package names are case sensitive in Java.

Comment: `indexOf()` won't work because we don't know which/how many whitespace characters to expect, so you would have to use `Matcher.find()` instead.  But `split()` is definitely the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: @AlanMoore "[...]we don't know which/how many whitespace characters to expect," <-- sorry, but I see no relationship at all between whitespaeces and the text to search; unless you mean that there can be an arbitrary number of spaces between `package` and `.com`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  And according to the OP's comment, that was indeed the problem.